# ActiveRecords where I filter the the value of by giving ids of other table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I'm having an issue figuring out how a specific query could be done.

I'm trying to get all the rows where a date is between two other dates (these two dates are columns in a table).The thing is these dates are all ids (foreign keys) that are associated to another table.

The structure of the two tables are:

```
**ReservationDate**

 - id
 - date (which is the date)
```

---

```
**Reservation**

 - id
 - from_date_id
 - to_date_id
```

if they weren't id's of the date table, I would've simply done

```
Reservation.where("(?) BETWEEN from_date AND to_date",date)
```

However, they are ids of the ReservationDate table and I'm unable to figure out a way to do it.

Ideally, something like that would work. But it doesn't.

```
Reservation.where("(?) BETWEEN from_date_id.date AND to_date_id.date",date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to join the tables to query them:

```rb
Reservation.
  joins(
    'reservation_dates AS from_dates ON reservations.from_date_id = from_dates.id').
  joins(
    'reservation_dates AS to_dates ON reservations.to_date_id = to_dates.id').
  where('(?) BETWEEN from_dates.date AND to_dates.date', date)
```

I'm curious though, what is the point of the `reservation_dates` table?